# Chrome extension popup on-click or on load event

Tags: events, google-chrome-extension, onclick, popup

Here I am writing a solution for getting click event or load event upon popup opening in chrome extension.

There is not such event for that like`chrome.popup.onClick` or `chrome.popup.onLoad`.

There's a `chrome.browserAction` but it does not triggered upon popup. Here it's documentation regarding this statement [Click here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/browserAction/)

Here's a simple solution to that...

use `window.onload` method

```
window.onload = function() {
    console.log('Popup opened');
}
```

Comment: There's no need for `onload` because the popup's scripts run each time the popup is opened so you can simply put the code at the beginning of the popup script.

Comment: Yes that's also a way, Thank you